# Can Python selenium be used to click on webpage labels?

Tags: selenium, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am working on third party applications where on the page too many `labels` are used as link or navigate to another page. So does python can do such tasks or read the page select list values?

I am using python 2.7 and selenium.

**EDIT**

There is a label called `configuration` see the corresponding code below:

```
<td class="tabtext-unsel"><nobr><a href="/aems/configuration/configurationlist.do" class="tabtext-unsel">Configuration</a></nobr></td>
                <td class="unselected_tab_mid"><img src="/simpletrade/default/images/background/spacer.gif" width="16" height="25"></td>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can.  A label is implemented in HTML as `<LABEL FOR="field_id">label text</LABEL>`, and you can use it in an XPath locator in Selenium.

---

(Update after edit of question)

That's not a label in HTML, but it's still possible using an XPath locator.  It's not even particularly difficult.  Both `<TD>` elements are children of the same `<TR>` element, so something like this will do the job: `//tr[td/a[.='Configuration']]/td/img` will match the `<IMG>` element.  But if all you want to do is locate the link, it's even easier: `//tr/td/a[.='Configuration']`

Comment: Does `XPath` is the only way to implement to solve this or any other also?

Comment: I want to click on that `Configuration` on the page and navigate to next page.

Comment: Then that last version ought to be the answer for you.

Comment: Okay,I will try now,If any issue will let you know!